# Twitter bootstrap rails error. "undefined local variable or method `flash'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I added twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.1) to my gemfile and then ran "bundle install". Next I ran "rails g bootstrap:install" and everything was fine. To generate the layout I did the following and got an error:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:todo my$ rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed 
Bootstrap helpers installs to application_helper...
      insert  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml
(erb):67:in `block in template': undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<Bootstrap::Generators::LayoutGenerator:0x00000102bb2c10> (NameError)
    from (erb):66:in `each'
    from (erb):66:in `template'
    from /Users/my/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:838:in `eval'
```

How do I take care of this? I'm running rails 3.2.1, ruby 1.9.3p0, and am using 'haml-rails'.

Comment: open an issue on github repository ?

Answer (score 2):

Update your Gemfile with

`gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'`

Comment: After doing this, I also had to remove the gem from `group :assets` for things to work: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/338#issuecomment-17107619.